# Raster data to polygons to compute averages in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I am interested in calculating precipitation averages globally. My data is contained in a RasterStack object in R and is globally distributed precipitation data. However, I only want to isolate land areas to compute the mean of those separately. What I would like to do is somehow isolate those grid cells whose centers overlap with land and then compute the annual mean. I already first created a raster stack object, called "RCP1pctCO2Mean", which contains the mean values of interest but is globally distributed data. There are 138 layers, with each layer representing one year.

Thus, what I would like to do is the following:

1. Convert raster to polygon but retain the original 138 raster layers when converted
2. Specify which grid cells are land (i.e. those grid cell centers/coordinates that fall on land)
3. Compute annual precipitation averages across these land grid cells.

My raster stack object "RCP1pctCO2Mean" has the following attributes:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192, 138  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin,  
ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       :    layer.1,    layer.2,    layer.3,    layer.4,    layer.5,       
layer.6,    layer.7,    layer.8,    layer.9,   layer.10,   layer.11,   
layer.12,   layer.13,   layer.14,   layer.15, ... 
min values  : 0.42964514, 0.43375653, 0.51749371, 0.50838983, 0.45366730,    
0.53099146, 0.49757186, 0.45697752, 0.41382199, 0.46082401, 0.45516687, 
0.51857087, 0.41005131, 0.45956529, 0.47497867, ... 
max values  :   96.30350,  104.08584,   88.92751,   97.49373,   89.57201,   
90.58570,   86.67651,   88.33519,   96.94720,  101.58247,   96.07792,   
93.21948,   99.59785,   94.26218,   90.62138, ...
```

Previously, I tried isolating a specific region by specifying a range of longitudes and latitudes to obtain the means and medians for that region, just like this:

```
>expansion1<-expand.grid(103:120, 3:15) #This is a range of longitudes and then latitudes
>lonlataaa<-extract(RCP1pctCO2Mean, expansion1)
>Columnaaa<-colMeans(lonlataaa)

#Packages loaded        
library(raster)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(rasterVis)
```

However, with this above approach, too much water can mix with land areas, and if I narrow the latitude/longitude range on land, I might miss too much land to compute the mean meaningfully.

Therefore, with this RasterStack, would it be possible to create a condition that tells R that if the "center point" or centroid of each grid cell (with each grid cell center representing a specific latitude/longitude coordinate) happens to fall on land, then it would be considered as land (i.e. that would be TRUE - if not, then FALSE, or maybe somehow use 0s or 1s)? Even if a grid cell happens to have water mixed with land, but the center point/centroid of the grid is on land, that would be considered as land. I would like to do this for specific countries, too, to compute national averages the same way.

I want the individual 138 layers/years to be retained, so that all the Year 1s can be averaged across all relevant grid cells, then all Year 2s, then all Year 3s, then all Year 4s, etc. (to create a time series later). I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but what I did first was take the "RCP1pctCO2Mean" RasterStack and created a SpatialPolygonsDataframe using:

```
trans <- raster::rasterToPolygon(RCP1pctCO2Mean)    
trans

class      : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 8192 
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables  : 138
names      :          layer.1,          layer.2,          layer.3,          layer.4,          layer.5,          layer.6,          layer.7,          layer.8,          layer.9,          layer.10,        layer.11,          layer.12,          layer.13,          layer.14,          layer.15, ... 
min values  : 0.429645141288708, 0.433756527757047, 0.517493712584313, 0.508389826053265, 0.453667300300907, 0.530991463885754,  0.4975718597839, 0.456977516231847, 0.413821991744321, 0.460824014230889, 0.45516687008843, 0.518570869929649, 0.410051312472821, 0.459565291388527, 0.474978673081429, ... 
max values  :  96.3034965348338,  104.085840813594,  88.9275127089197,  97.4937326695693,  89.5720053000712,  90.5857030396531, 86.6765123781949,  88.3351859796546,  96.947199473011,  101.582468961459, 96.0779212204739,  93.2194802269814,  99.5978503841538,  94.2621847475029,  90.6213755054263, ...
```

Does this first step make sense? Does this retain the original raster data, but now in polygon form? If so, is it then possible to somehow just isolate an all-land polygon, and then somehow specify which cells are considered land, and then compute averages for each year across the grid cells?

I have looked previously for any procedure example to do this, but I have not yet come across anything too specific.

Thank you for your time, and any help would be immensely valuable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to convert your raster to a polygon.  It is better to use a shapefile to mask your raster and leave only the points that are overland. If your precipitation data is already in the format of a rasterStack called "RCP1pctCO2Mean" then you can do this:

```
require(maptools)
require(raster)
data(wrld_simpl) ##this loads a coarse-resolution global shapefile from the maptools package


##GLOBAL EXAMPLE
##isolate only points on land
##wrld_simpl and RCP1pctCO2Mean have the same CRS so can be used directly
all_land_vals = mask(RCP1pctCO2Mean,wrld_simpl)

##get mean value for all points but for each layer separately 
cellStats(all_land_vals, stat='mean')


##COUNTRY EXAMPLE
##isolate only points on Brazil
country=wrld_simpl[which(wrld_simpl$NAME=="Brazil"),]
country_vals = mask(RCP1pctCO2Mean,country)

##get mean value for all points in given country but for each layer separately 
cellStats(country_vals, stat='mean')
```

N.B. your precipitation data is quite coarse so you may want to `disaggregate` it first. Also you methodology of calculating the mean directly is flawed as latlong is a geographic coordinate system and the further away from the equator a pixel is the smaller the land area it actually represent. To overcome this technically precipitation values should be weighted to reflect distance from equator.

Comment: Yes, this worked absolutely fine!!! Thank you so much! And yes, I am aware of the pixel size issue. Does it relate to taking the cosine of the latitude? If so, something like this? weight <- cos(RCP1pctCO2Mean*(pi/180)) ? Or is this incorrect? I receive odd values doing this, so I would assume no? Thanks, again!

Comment: Yes, The distance represented by 1 degree of longitude is proportional to the cosine of the latitude. However you must first convert from rasterstack to data frame using rasterToPoints(). This will give you a data frame with lat, long and then your 138 precipitation observations. You can calculate your weight on the latitude in this data frame

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I converted the RCP1pctCO2Mean raster stack like this: newraster<-rasterToPoints(RCP1pctCO2Mean). I then proceeded to do assign weights like this: weight <- cos(newraster*(pi/180)). However, this yields strange but identical precipitation values (i.e. all values are 0.97 to 0.99, which is odd). I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly (if there is anything incorrect) - could it be that the pi/180 is not necessary? Also, once this is done, how to revert to a raster stack with the new values? Thanks, again!

Comment: Many thanks, again, for your help with this! Just one last question, but does wrld_simpl include local/point location shapefiles? If not, I can simply download these, although I would just likely need to project them to match my raster projection.

Comment: No, wrld_simpl is just a coarse resolution global shapefile with country boundaries. As you said, you would need to download the required shapefile and reproject it if needed using `spTransform`

Comment: Thanks, again. Finally, is it possible to use wrld_simpl to plot without using a mask - for example, if I wanted to plot land + water? I tried this using: >waterCO2<-mask(RCP1pctCO2Median, wrld_simpl, inverse=TRUE)
> landCO2 <- mask(RCP1pctCO2Median,wrl_simpl)
> newly <- waterCO2 + landCO2
>plot(newly) This only returns blank plots, however, when I tried this, but wouldn't this be how we would join land and water areas? Thanks, and that would be all for this!

Comment: For land and water together can't you just use RCP1pctCO2Median without masking?

Comment: I tried doing that, like this: data("wrld_simpl"), > b<-wrld_simpl > newCO2<-c(RCP1pctCO2Median,b), >plot(newCO2,) but I end up with the following error: "Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'" I am not sure why that occurs. When applying the mask, it works just fine, but plotting without it results in that error. Why would that error display without masking? Thanks,

Comment: I actually found another way to consider all grid points, even when using a mask, All I did was select a small country (an island) and simply applied the inverse of the mask for that country. This allowed the rest of the globe to be displayed, which is pretty much okay. :)